# Rewrite the raw DB query to query builder in laravel 8

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I'm trying to convert a raw query to a Laravel query builder but when I use the raw method I can't make it to write in a query builder

Here is my raw query

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(a.qty,' ',a.uqc) SEPARATOR ' ,') as quantity,a.exporter 
FROM (select sum(shipping_bill_items.quantity) as qty, `exporters`.name as exporter,`shipping_bill_items`.uqc
from `shipping_bill_items`
inner join `shipping_bill` on `shipping_bill`.`id` = `shipping_bill_items`.`shipping_bill_id`
inner join `exporters` on `exporters`.`id` = `shipping_bill`.`exporter_id`
group by `exporters`.name,`shipping_bill_items`.`uqc`
ORDER BY `exporters`.`name` ASC ) a 
group by a.exporter;
```

I tried to write seems couldn't help any please help me to rewrite this!

below which I tired to rewrite attempt to solve the problem

```
$Details=DB::select('a.exporter')
        ->addSelect(DB::raw("GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(a.qty,' ', a.uqc) SEPARATOR ' ,') as quantity"))
        ->from("select sum(shipping_bill_items.quantity) as qty, 'exporters'.name as exporter, 'shipping_bill_items'.uqc from 'shipping_bill_items' inner join 'shipping_bill' on 'shipping_bill'.'id' = 'shipping_bill_items'.'shipping_bill_id' inner join 'exporters' on 'exporters'.'id' = 'shipping_bill'.'exporter_id' group by 'exporters'.name, 'shipping_bill_items'.'uqc' ORDER BY 'exporters'.'name' ASC as a")
        ->groupBy('a.exporter')
        ->get();
```

I tried to add an image for references but I couldn't add it  here is the table that I want  to achieve a result

| quantity | exporter |
| --- | --- |
| 45.65 MTS | 1st Exporter |
| 1404.25 LTR,114170 NO | 2nd Exporter |
| 5168 NOS,47856 PCS,74648 SET | 3ed Exporter |

Comment: By "Laravel query" I assume you mean Eloquent ORM? Using `DB::select()` is not as same as using Eloquent ORM. Share your model relations and mention what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Laravel Query I mean to say Laravel Query builder not using Eloquent ORM, sorry my bad I have to write what I'm trying to achieve, yes I edited my question 
I couldn't add an image please review the table

Comment: Seems like you could just run the subquery `a` in Query Builder, and then use some `Collection` method to group the result.